# Wordpress and flush_rules

Tags: wordpress, flush, rules

I have a site with several custom rewrite rules like this:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'add_my_rewrite') );

public function add_my_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_tag('%get-continent%','([^&]+)');

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('something/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12345&get-continent=$matches[1]','top');         
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);
}
```

I copied it from old codex example and searching here. They all work fine but they do lots and lots of update on the DB.

After doing a little research I found out that codex also discourage firing it on init (unlike in the example that was provided). It's a little broad on which hook should I fire it. After a little research appears that the best time is on plugin activation.

Question: I can't deactivate those plugins in the prod site, I can replace "init" with something else es. plugin activation (not sure yet what is the hook) but will the roules work if I comment it out? Do I have to fire it some other time other than on plugin activation? Isn't it going to be accidentally overwritten? Can I simpli comment out the add_action since I won't be activating or deactivating the plugin?

As always, thank you guys.

Comment: yes you can comment out flush rewrite rules. You can actually flush the rewrite rules manually anyway, this happens when you save the permalink settings on the admin side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false); part, I had to leave this:

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'add_my_rewrite'), 10, 0);
```

and the function became:

```
public function add_my_rewrite() {

    add_rewrite_tag('%get-continent%','([^&]+)');

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_rule('something/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12345&get-continent=$matches[1]','top');         
}
```

It works just fine, ideally I'll have to fire the flush on activation or eventually just go into Settings / Permalinks and hit Save.